# (Slowly) Making Popups in WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, iframe, popup, readfile

.. hoping that someone can help.

I am creating my own Popup functionality for my WordPress site.

Many parts of the code below has been gleaned from the web, and it all works.

With it I am able to select several <a href help-links on a html page, that then opens a popup on screen, with each popup having different content.

As I say, it works, but not well, in that I have a performance issue -- that I can't seem to pin down.

Primarily: I can actually see the included file being filled in, the slight delay is only on screen for a brief second, but I can see it.

Conclusion: something's amiss.

Perhaps one of you most excellent programmers can pass an experienced eye over the code, .. and then point out anything that pops up? - Or not!

BACKGROUND:-
/* [ css ] - [ js ] are directories that are both off of the theme directory path, all working.
In my functions.php file I am enqueueing the [ jquery-ui.css ] in the footer.
After a lot of trial and error, I'm now putting the [ jquery-ui-min.js ] file in the header.
BTW: I'm not using the version numbers, they're just there out of habit.
I have put [ true - the default ] in the example below, just to demonstrate the difference.
*/

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-effects', get_template_directory_uri( __FILE__ ) . '/css/jquery-ui.css' , array(),  '1.0.0',  true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-core-ui', get_template_directory_uri( __FILE__ ) . '/js/jquery-ui-min.js', array( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-dialog' ), '1.0.0',  false );
```

HTML:-
!>- On my web page I have a Div surrounding an iFrame: used to accept file input. ->

```
<div id="somediv" title="&equiv; [ POPUP ] &equiv;" style="display:none;">
    <iframe id="thedialog" width="100%" height="100%" ></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS:-
/* I am simply using the common [ ui-dialog ] class found in the [ jquery-ui.css ] file. */

```
.ui-dialog {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: .2em;
    outline: 0;
    background: blue; 
}
```

JS:-
// Here is the js code that I'm employing.

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) 
{
    $( ".trigger" ).click( function ()
    {
        // The code below constructs a clean path to my WordPress page.
        // It is saved under a '/cuttings/' parent, and it works ..
        
        var submitUrl = document.location.origin + '/cuttings/' +  $(this).attr("href");       
        $("#thedialog").attr('src',  submitUrl );        
        $("#somediv").dialog(
        {  
            width: 500,
            height: 500,
            modal: true,
            close: function () 
            {
                $("#thedialog").attr('src', "about:blank");
            }           
        });
        return false;
    });   
});
```

WORDPRESS:-
/* I have constructed a completely blank template in WordPress, that is as follows. */

```
<?php
/* 
Template Name: WordPress Blank
*/
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) :     
        the_post();
        the_content();
     endwhile; 
else: 
    echo '<p>Nothing Found!</p>';
endif
?>
```

It works, and simply outputs the contents of the WordPress page with no formatting. Also: the WordPress help pages stored under /cuttings/ are all saved using this template.

As I say: it all works as expected, except for that slight delay in filling in the iFrame popup.

So, can anyone see an issue (???)

Comment: Loading a page in an iframe is not instantaneous the same way loading a new page in a browser tab isn't. Requests have to be made to server(s) for all the resources and then the result needs to be rendered

Answer (score 0):

It is slow indeed, but if submitUrl does not have an ending '/', i see that there is 2 requests for each click, an the first is always fails with 301 temporary moved status. Very strange.

Comment: I was wondering if this technique would be faster if you use json files with js XMLHttpRequest object, huh? The json files could go to the same sub-folder but it won't take the whole page to load in an iFrame that goes through the wordpress page-creation mechanism.